# Bash alias to compile coffeescript from within file

Tags: bash, vim, coffeescript

Inside vim while writing a coffeescript file I use the following command to compile:

```
  !coffeescript -c %
```

I tried creating a bash alias for this called `cc`. Inside my root path I put the file named `cc` with the following contents `!coffeescript -c %` and then try to run it from within my coffeescript file but it does not work.

How can I create an alias that will compile coffeescript while I am inside Vim editing the file?

Comment: How about using a `coffeescript --watch`?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to create a vim mapping. Something like this in your ~/.vimrc

```
nmap <Leader>cc :!coffeescript -c %<CR>
```

Then, in normal mode, you hit <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><sup>1</sup>, the mapping invokes the command.

<sup>1.</sup> backslash is the default "mapleader" character, you can define it to be something else.

Comment: I set the mapping but when I try to execute /cc from inside a coffee file it says, "E486: Pattern not found: cc"

Comment: I don't follow you. What do you mean "inside a coffee file"? Are you adding that line to your source code? Why are you trying to compile your source code from your source code?